# How to batch submit amp pages to google

Tags: amp-html

How to batch submit amp pages to google? Is this possible to via sort of API?

At moment I am doing this manually one-by-one via Google's Webmaster tools.

I have over 200 pages and doing this manually is laborious.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need to manually add AMPs. If you [reference your AMPs from your canonical pages](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/guides/discovery) via

```
<link rel="amphtml" href="https://www.example.com/url/to/amp/document.html"
```

the Google crawler will automatically pickup your AMPs.

Comment: Hi Sebastian is it possible to test it in local?

Comment: @MMR You can append #development=1 at the end of urls and reload the page. Under the console tab of the chrome dev tools, you will see whether the page pass amp validation or not. If not, it will tell you what needs to be fixed.

Comment: @user1275105,Yes I did it but my doubt is how lo load the amp page of a regular page, when mobile version is turned on?

Comment: Make sure that all versions of your webpage (canonical and mobile) link to the AMP. You can use the AMP URL API to test whether an AMP version has been discovered by the Google crawler: https://ampbyexample.com/advanced/using_the_amp_url_api/